# Importing files with two row as a column name

Tags: r, excel

I am new to R so this question may be too simple for most.

I am currently using R to import values and datas from my Excel file.
However the first two row I would like to set as my column name. Can anyone advice me on what should be done? For e.g. col.names=??

[image]

I would like my column name to be

`NAMEA, PRODUCT1B, PRODUCT2C, PRODUCT3D` so on and so for.

*Please do not tell me to change my column name at Excel as there are a lot of columns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
#pasting the first row with the column name and assigning them as column names
colnames(df) <- paste0(colnames(df), df[1, ])
```

if you now want to remove the first row from your data frame then you can use

```
df[-1, ]
```

where `df` is your data frame

Comment: `df[1, ]` gives the first row, I think you mean `paste0(names(df), df[1, ])`

Comment: yes, you are right.  We need to paste the `colnames` with the first row and then remove the first row. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an end-to-end solution in addition to what @Ronak has mentioned.  I would use `read.csv()` without a header, to give you two actual rows in your data frame.  Then create the new column names using `paste0()`, assign them, and remove the first two rows.

```
# read in CSV file from Excel, using comma as a separator
input <- read.csv(file="path/to/excelFile.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE,
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# create new column names as a composite of the first two rows
new_names <- paste0(as.character(input[1,]), as.character(input[2,]))

names(input) <- new_names          # assign the new column names
input <- input[3:nrow(input), ]    # subset off the first two rows
```

Comment: will `header = F` help? I mean isn't it the same thing?

Comment: I don't know what the default behavior is, but it makes sense to me to tell R to treat the entire file as tabular data, rather than assigning the first row as names.

Comment: @RonakShah `header=F` and `header=FALSE` are somewhat the same, but I would prefer the long format.  Anyway, plus one for this

Comment: @akrun I dont think they are 'somewhat' same,they are completely same and my remark was regarding something else.

Comment: @RonakShah My remark was that is better to use the full `TRUE` instead of `T`.  I have no intention to go over your `something else` remark.

Comment: @RonakShah As you are making comments like `completely same` and stuff, try assigning an object with to `T` `T <- 1:5` and then read some data  `df1 <- read.table(text="Col1 Col2
5 7
7 8", sep="", header=T)`    However you can't do `TRUE <- :1:5`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
a <- c("NAME", "PRODUCT1", "PRODUCT2", "PRODUCT3")
b <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
str_c(a,b)#"NAMEA"     "PRODUCT1B" "PRODUCT2C" "PRODUCT3D"
```

You can then use the output of str_c as your column names and then delete the first two rows of your data frame.